# get an runtime error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

The problem is, I am getting the runtime error when I trying to get firebase data into a RecyclerView.
Error is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
```

I have implemented it last time but now I can't get it what have I done wrong.

My main class setting firebase initialization-

```
 public class Shayari extends AppCompatActivity {
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private DatabaseReference reference;
        TextView texttest;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_shayari);

        texttest=findViewById(R.id.test);//just for test


        reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Catogory/Love");
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataModel,DataViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataModel, DataViewHolder>(
                DataModel.class,
                R.layout.item_recyclerview,
                DataViewHolder.class,
                reference) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(DataViewHolder viewHolder, DataModel model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                viewHolder.setShayari(model.getShayari());

            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        texttest.setText(reference.toString());
    }

    public class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView text_title,text_shayari;
        public DataViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            text_title=itemView.findViewById(R.id.titletext);
            text_shayari=itemView.findViewById(R.id.shayaritext);
        }

        public void setShayari(String shayari) {

            text_shayari.setText(shayari);
        }

        public void setTitle (String title){

            text_title.setText(title);

        }
    }
}
```

Model Class for getting data-

```
class DataModel {
    private String titles, shayaris;

    public DataModel() {
    }

    public DataModel(String titles, String shayaris) {
        this.titles = titles;
        this.shayaris = shayaris;
    }


    public String getTitle()
    {
        return titles;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
       this.titles = title;
    }

    public String getShayari() {
        return shayaris;
    }

    public void setShayari(String shayari) {
        this.shayaris = shayari;
    }
}
```

This is my firebase hierarchy structure

https://unikshayari.firebaseio.com/Catogory/Love/s01/shayaris "data"

Answer (score 1):

the inner class must be static.

change this

```
 public class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
```

to

```
 public static class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
```